# EasyQRCodeJS: The width doesn't render correctly

Tags: ionic3, qr-code

I'm trying to create qrCode in my view using [EasyQRCodeJS](https://github.com/ushelp/EasyQRCodeJS),I'm using Ionic/Cordova.

The options:

```
let qrcodeWidth = this.qrcodeEl.nativeElement.offsetWidth*0.8;
let options = {
  text: qrCodeText,
  logo: "assets/imgs/qrCode/logo.svg",
  logoBackgroundTransparent: true,
  width: qrcodeWidth,
  height: qrcodeWidth,
  logoWidth: 59,
  drawer: 'svg',
}
let qrcode = new QRCode(this.qrcodeEl.nativeElement, options);
```

I test that with a `div#qrcodeEl` that has 300px in the width so the `qrcodeWidth` is 240px, the render return qrcode has 260px instead of 240px.

I even try to for the width using `onRenderingStart()` function, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after generating the svg:

```
// Remove attributes width and height and add viewbox with width and hight so it will be resize in the middle
setTimeout(_=>{
  this.qrcodeEl.nativeElement.childNodes[0].attributes.removeNamedItem('width');
  this.qrcodeEl.nativeElement.childNodes[0].attributes.removeNamedItem('height');
  this.qrcodeEl.nativeElement.childNodes[0].viewBox.baseVal.width = qrcodeWidthScaled;
  this.qrcodeEl.nativeElement.childNodes[0].viewBox.baseVal.height = qrcodeWidthScaled;
}, 1000);
```